# What episode does Natsu achieve Natural Dragon Force?

Tags: fairy-tail

So far,

> Natsu has been shown to achieve Etherion Dragon Force in his fight with Jellal, and Flames of Rebuke Dragon Force.

In what episode does he achieve Natural Dragon Force without eating any outside elements? I've tried researching but I still don't know when he goes Natural Dragon Force.

Answer (score 1):

This happens only once so far in the anime and Manga, and it is in the Tartaros arc (the last arc of the Anime currently, as it is on Hiatus), during his fight against

> Mard Gear Tartaros

During this fight

> Natsu and Grey are generally losing against Mard Gear's Full power. Eventually, Mard Gear uses his ultimate move, a curse meant to kill even Zeref, and both Natsu and Grey get hit by it and are believed dead for a short time. It is then revealed that Gray was able to counter it using his newly gifted Devil Slayer Ice Magic, and is rendered mostly incapacitated for doing so. Natsu gets enraged and enters Dragon force without eating anything and for a short while overwhelms Mard Gear, which shows that he indeed fully achieved Dragon force, since he and Grey together were unable to do much but take a beating before this.

The event itself happens in chapter 411, which should be episode 263 according to the wiki,
http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Force